# Tried to initialize sapi5, error

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition

```
In[2]: import pyttsx
In[3]: import speech_recognition
In[4]: speech_engine = pyttsx.init("sapi5")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Keshav\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyttsx\__init__.py", line 37, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "C:\Users\Keshav\Anaconda3\lib\weakref.py", line 131, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: 'sapi5'
```

I'm running Python 3.5(Anaconda) on Win10 64bit. Not sure if its a driver issue on my OS or something else. 
Kindly let me know the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is simple, pyttsx does work only with python 2+ :(  #facepalm

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have a solution. You just have to cheat with the `__init__.py` here.

Go to `C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\pyttsx` directory.

Then open to edit the `__init__.py` file.

Find this part:

```
except KeyError:
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
    _activeEngines[driverName] = eng
return eng
```

Remove the `KeyError` like this and save.

```
except :
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
    _activeEngines[driverName] = eng
return eng
```